# How to access instance variables and methods in Java

Tags: java

This is a Java program for accessing instance variables and methods (the system throws a syntax error on the token "int" import expected in the global declaration **"int puppyAge;": -**

Is there an option to declare the variable globally:

```
package instancevariableandmethods;
int puppyAge;

public class Instancevariable {
    public Instancevariable(String name) {
        System.out.println("The name is:" + name);
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        puppyAge = age;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        System.out.println("Puppy's age is: " + puppyAge);
        return puppyAge;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instancevariable myPuppy = new Instancevariable("tommy");

        /* Call class method to set puppy's age */
        myPuppy.setAge(2);

        /* Call another class method to get puppy's age */
        myPuppy.getAge();

        /* You can access instance variable as follows as well */
        System.out.println("Variable Value:" + myPuppy.puppyAge );
    }
}
```

Comment: depends on what you mean by 'globally'. Java doesn't have global variables, everything is within a class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare your *variable* like below:

```
public class Instancevariable
{
    int puppyAge;
    //// The rest of your code
}
```

Example - global and local variable declarations

```
public class Car {
    private int speed; // Private variable declaration
    public int wheels; // Public variable declaration

    /* ...constructor, etc... */

    public void speedUp() {
        // Local variable declaration, in line assignment,
        // only seen within the speedUp method
        int speedIncrease = 10;
        speed += speedIncrease;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any global variables as such in Java. There are static variables at the class level, but they are shared across all instances of the class.

In this case, you need a class field:

```
package instancevariableandmethods;


public class Instancevariable
{
    int puppyAge;

    public Instancevariable(String name) {

        System.out.println("The name is: " + name);
    }


    public void setAge(int age) {

        puppyAge = age;
    }


    public int getAge() {

        System.out.println("Puppy's age is: " + puppyAge);
        return puppyAge;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Instancevariable myPuppy = new Instancevariable("tommy");

        /* Call the class method to set the puppy's age */
        myPuppy.setAge(2);

        /* Call another class method to get the puppy's age */
        myPuppy.getAge();

        /* You can access instance variable as follows as well */
        System.out.println("Variable Value: " + myPuppy.puppyAge);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `int puppyAge;` belongs in the class, not above:

```
public class Instancevariable {
    int puppyAge;
    // The rest of your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong. You can declare a class variable inside your class. If you want to make it super global, use "public".

```
public class TemplateVO
{
    public int puppyAge;
    // The rest of your code
```